# RouterLink attrs is readonly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm starting with VueRouter in Vue.js and I'm getting this errors:

```
[Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

found in

---> <RouterLink>
   <SecondNav> at resources\assets\js\modules\livegame\player\SecondNav.vue
     <Player> at resources\assets\js\modules\livegame\player\Player.vue
       <Root>

[Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly.

found in

---> <RouterLink>
   <SecondNav> at resources\assets\js\modules\livegame\player\SecondNav.vue
     <Player> at resources\assets\js\modules\livegame\player\Player.vue
       <Root>
```

I have reduced everything I could and the result is that problem is only in router. I did it according docs and I don't have any idea where is problem. Here are my components:

SecondNav.vue

```
<template>
<div class="row second-top-nav">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-11">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li>
                <router-link to='/public/livegame/player/history'>
                    History
                </router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

Player.vue

```
<template>
<div>
    <second-nav></second-nav>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import SecondNav from './SecondNav';

export default {
    components: {
        SecondNav
    },
}
</script>
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

import History from './history/History';

export default new VueRouter({
   mode: 'history',
   routes: [
    {path: '/public/livegame/player/history', component: History, name: 'player_history'},
   ],
   linkActiveClass: "active", // active class for non-exact links.
});
```

Start point player.js

```
window.Event = new Vue();

import Vue from 'vue';

import router from './router'
import Player from './Player.vue';

let vm = new Vue({
   el: '#player',
   router,
   components: {
      Player    
   },
});

window.vm = vm;
```

I don't know where is problem or what I'm doing wrong. Everything in application seems to work without problem but these notifications doesn't look that all is right. I'm using Vue.js version 2.5.16 and VueRouter version 3.0.1.

Answer (score 5):

Having multiple Vue instances can lead to this problem...

I **fixed** this warning: Vue warn $attrs is readonly. found in ...

**by *removing* line**: `import Vue from 'vue'`

while *keeping*: `import VueRouter from 'vue-router'`

Reason why it fixed: vue was being loaded twice. Vue is imported at the top of VueRouter. There's no need to import it before VueRouter.

Comment: I solved it similar: In main.js remove `import Vue from 'vue'` and leave only the router and the other things below (assuming you're using vue router)

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple Vue instances can lead to this problem. In your `player.js` file you do you

```
window.Event = new Vue();
```

then immediately after:

```
let vm = new Vue({ ... })
```

Try removing the first `new Vue`, that should help. Since you are registering the router globally by calling `Vue.use(VueRouter)` you have two vue instances, both with their own router. When the second instance mounts and tries to register the router, since the first instance already did so, you get the `readonly` error.

Also `import` instances are hoisted to the top of the file, so although you declare `window.Event = new Vue` at the top, realistically the `import` instances are occurring before any variable declaration and assignment.