# vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly. On socket event

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vue-component

I have a blog comments and I was trying to add a comment with the data from socket server, but when the data arrives in the client side and attempting to push it on my comment property there is this error in my console saying

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <Single Post> at resources/assets/guest/views/Single Post.vue
         <App> at resources/assets/guest/App.vue
           <Root>



<template>
    <!-- post comments -->
    <div class="section-row">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h3 class="title">{{comments.length}} Comment<span v-if="comments.length > 1">s</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="post-comments">

            <!-- comment -->
            <div class="media" v-for="comment in comments">
                <div class="media-left">
                    <img class="media-object" src="/blog/img/avatar-2.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="media-heading">
                        <h4>{{comment.user.name}}</h4>
                        <span class="time">{{comment.created_at | dateFromNow}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
                    <a href="#" class="reply">Reply</a>

                    <post-reply :replies="comment.replies"/>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /comment -->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /post comments -->
</template>


export default {
        sockets: {
            comment_added(comment) {        
            this.comments.push(comment);    
            },
        },
        props : {
            postComments : {
                type : Array,
                required : true
            }
        },
        data : ()=>({
            comments : []
        }),
        watch : {
            postComments : function(val){
                this.comments = val;
            }
        },
    }
```

I use the vue-socket globally and is successfully connected with the socket server. But when I tried to emit comment_added from the socket server the error occurs.

The output seems right. It successfully pushed the new comment but it's just annoying looking at the error in my console.

Comment: The error references a `router-link` inside `Single Post.vue`. I don't see a `router-link` in the code you've posted so I'm guessing this isn't `Single Post.vue`?

Comment: that component is comment.vue. The error occurs only after emiting event from the socket server. I dont change anything on the data binding with the router-link

Comment: Have you ruled out this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936163

Comment: I read it already, but seems their solutions are not working in my problem

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated my vue instance I had imported a vue through script, and is duplicated when I include vue which I have downloaded via npm;

I fixed it by removing the script the import's vue which is inside my body tag